# implementing constraint layout in scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

scroll view not working when implementing like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/Constraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.05" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

i saw  a post where we can anchor the elements to the guideline by increasing it beyond the 100% but when i am using this the scroll isn't working even the textview isn't visible anymore how do i fix this

Comment: Can you please elaborate it? A screenshot of **Required** and **Current** will be more helpful.

Comment: What if you use `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline"` instead of `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` in **`TextView`**.

Comment: @JeelVankhede not working that way

Comment: the text view is at the bottom of the constraint layout like the guideline is over 100% i used a constraint layout inside a scroll view as in if i scroll i have to see the text view not able to figure out how to do it the scroll isn't working @SanthoshJoseph

Comment: yes thats what i want @SanthoshJoseph

Comment: its not that i just want a single textview to be visbile i want the scroll to work on the constraint layout @SanthoshJoseph

Comment: Can you please explain about the guideline usage in your xml?

Comment: to see if the scroll is working @SanthoshJoseph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your code should work when there is enough elements to scroll, try to add a higher margintop to the text view and you will see the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="630dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a try with [BottomSheet](https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066) ?

[image]

Comment: i have a continuous structure of components from the top to the bottom in the constraint layout i want the scroll in the constraint layout so that the bottom elements are also available when i scroll thank you

Answer (score 0):

add the below linearlayout into scrollview and add your constraint layout in this linearlayout

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
```

i think it will work